# Git doesn't remove new files on checkout of prior snapshot

Tags: git, git-checkout

I began working with a particular repository at snapshot `a0c53b9`.  I changed some files and added others in directories `kernel/` and `u-boot/`, and committed snapshot `9c06fb7`.

As it turns out I will not be using my changes to `u-boot/`, but would still like to be able to refer back to them.  I consequently did the following:

```
git checkout a0c53b9 u-boot/
git commit -m "profound and eclectic description of change"
```

Strangely I find that while the checkout restored the files that had been modified from `9c06fb7` to `a0c53b9`, it did not delete the files that had been added in `a0c53b9`.  These are not untracked files, so the `git clean -fd` suggestion in numerous other answers doesn't apply.

Assume that preexisting file `u-boot/common/usb.c` was modified, and new file `u-boot/board/xilinx/zynq/crypto/sha.h` was added.  After `git checkout a0c53b9 u-boot/`, file `u-boot/common/usb.c` has been reverted to its `a0c53b9` state, but file `u-boot/board/xilinx/zynq/crypto/sha.h` is still present instead of having been removed.

Am I doing something wrong?  How do I get these previously added files to go away?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### How to do what you want

Summary of the problem: when you use `git checkout commit-hash path` (in this case `git checkout a0c53b9 u-boot/`), git extracts that path—in this case, a directory full of files—but does not `git rm` any files that are *not* in that particular commit that *are* currently in that directory.  This means that if you were to make a new commit now, it would have the older `u-boot` code, but would have the new files mixed in with the old code.

The easy solution is to, first, make sure you don't need any of those files—that there's no uncommitted work to save—and then just `git rm -rf u-boot/` (not regular `rm`) the entire directory.  This will clean out the work tree and schedule all the files for removal, but before you actually commit anything, *now* you run `git checkout a0c53b9 u-boot/`, which will re-populate the index and work-tree for the `u-boot/` files in commit `a0c53b9`.  The removed files that have no older version remain removed, and the removed files that have an older version are restored from the older version.

---

#### Background, or the TL;DR part: why git behaves this way

The `git checkout` command is really several (how many depends on how you count) different commands:

- `git checkout name` (where *`name`* names a valid, existing branch) switches from the current commit to a new commit, putting you on the given branch *`name`*.  This is true even if, per [`gitrevisions`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitrevisions.html), *`name`* ought to resolve to a commit ID rather than a branch name (though this case is quite rare and should not happen).  This operation can fail if some work-tree files would be clobbered (but `-f` will force the switch anyway).
- `git checkout hash` switches from the current commit to a new commit, taking you off any branch (into "detached HEAD" mode).  It's otherwise the same as giving a branch name.  The *`hash`* can be anything that resolves to a commit ID, including a tag or remote-tracking branch name; it just can't be an existing branch name since that falls into the first case.
- `git checkout -b name` creates a new branch using the given *`name`* (additional arguments can affect how the branch is created).  It generally won't fail since you'll generally create a new branch at the current commit, which means only the `HEAD` indirection needs to change: uncommitted work in the work-tree remains uncommitted.
- `git checkout -- path` extracts some file(s) from the index into the work-tree, clobbering any uncommitted work.  Note that if you `git add`-ed a *`path`* earlier, then modified the file some more, this restores the version you `git add`ed, not the version in the `HEAD` commit.
- `git checkout hash -- path` extracts some file(s) from the given *`hash`* into the work-tree, writing them *through* the index (i.e., the index entry is also updated).  It's otherwise the same as the previous (check out from index) method: in both cases the work-tree matches the index when the command finishes.  The *`hash`* argument can be anything that git can resolve to a tree: this includes branch, tag, and remote-tracking branch names.  Git does not change the current commit, just the index and work-tree.

Note that the first three listed forms carefully *avoid* clobbering work in the work-tree, while the last two deliberately clobber work.  (I personally think that at least these two modes should be different commands.  That is, it would be nice if `git <something-like-checkout>` was always safe and `git <something-like-clobbber>` was the "unsafe" command.  It would then be easier to remember when to be careful.)

When you did this:

> ```
> git checkout a0c53b9 u-boot/
> ```

you were using the last form of `git checkout`, i.e., `git checkout hash -- path`.  (The double dash here is not actually required.  It separates a hash from a path, and *is* required—at least potentially—when using the fourth form.  Suppose you want to check out a leet-speak file named `f33dc47` from the index.  But file-name `f33dca7`—"feed cat" in 1337—is also a valid hash prefix.  The double-dash is the way you tell git you're doing a fourth-form checkout rather than a second-form one.)

When you use either of the last two forms of `git checkout`, git is not *changing* your *current* commit, it's just *extracting some file(s)*.  In this case git will *not* remove files.  The files you extracted are "everything in `u-boot/`", and as you saw, git did update those files, it just did not remove any other files in `u-boot/`.  This is the correct behavior for `git checkout`.

In your case, you wanted to make a new commit that has "new everything else, but an old `u-boot/`, including *not* having the new `u-boot/` files that came along for the ride when we got everything".  So, how do you clean out the directory, to avoid having extra files?  The answer lies in noting that `git checkout hash -- path` writes through the index into the work-tree; so if you first empty out both the work-tree and the index of all files in that directory, then re-populate both from the old commit, you will get what you want.

Comment: Thank you for the answer.  I was a little taken aback by the `rm -rf u-boot/` until I realized it was actually `git rm -rf u-boot/` and that I didn't have uncommitted changes in that directory anyway.  The part of the answer that helped me was the "In  your case ..." paragraph with subsequent commands.  (And I have edited my question to correct the wrong hash that you pointed out.)

Comment: For the benefit of other readers, it may be worth removing the majority of this answer.  It is very complete, but most of it was not relevant to the actual problem, and I think that trimming it could make it even better.

Comment: I'll see if I can edit this so that the "how to" part comes first and the "how come it acts this way" part comes later.  While you didn't specifically ask *why* the extra files were retained, you did use the word "strangely", so I tried to address that as well.

Answer (score 0):

> How do I get these previously added files to go away?

You can always find out the SHA-1 of the desired file, check it out, add & commit it again with the desired content.

```
# Checkout the given file from a given SHA-1
git checkout SHA-1 -- full_path_fo_file
```

Another more simply option is to view the content of the old file (if you use IDE you usually will have local history of the file, or with `git log --follow` and once you have the content as before add & commit it.

Comment: I must be missing something:  My problem is with files that were not in the earlier commit, and which need to be removed.  When I try the equivalent of `git checkout a0c53b9 u-boot/board/xilinx/zynq/crypto/sha.h`, Git understandably tells me `error: pathspec '...' did not match any file(s) known to git.`

Comment: you need to add `--` before the file name like this: `git checkout a0c53b9 -- <path>`

Comment: Tried `git checkout a0c53b9 -- u-boot/board/xilinx/zynq/crypto/sha.h` and I still get the same result.  The `--` should only be necessary if any remaining arguments could be mistaken for hashes.